# Expectation value of total energy for the quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, superposition

A particles unnormalized wavefunction is given as

$$\psi(x)=2\psi_1+\psi_2+2\psi_3.$$

How can I find $\langle E\rangle $ without calculating        $\langle T\rangle$ or $\langle V\rangle     $ first? I'm pretty sure I have $\langle T\rangle      $ and $\langle    V  \rangle$ though, so is the only way to find $\langle E\rangle          $ is to add these two values together? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try operating the [Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)#The_Schr.C3.B6dinger_Hamiltonian) on the wave function.

Comment: @KyleKanos that's what I was going to do, but that will just give me kinetic plus potential (as I've calculated before). The question asks for the expectation values of E, T, then V, so I was wondering if there was a way to find the expectation values of E without using <T>+<V>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're specifically asked for the expectation values of $T$ and $V$ then the simplest way of getting $\langle E\rangle$ is simply adding $\langle T\rangle$ and $\langle V\rangle$. If you want a direct calculation, your quickest route is probably using the eigenvalue equation
$$H\psi_n=\hbar\omega(n+\tfrac12)\psi_n$$
and the orthonormality of the $\psi_n$.

Comment: I'm still a little confused how I calculate <H> from the above expression (please note that we haven't gotten up to Dirac notation yet in class).

Comment: Look at it this way: your expression for $\psi$ means that there's relative probabilities of 2$^2$, 1$^2$ and 2$^2$ of the particle being in state 1, 2 and 3, and therefore having energy $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$ respectively. After that it's classical probability work to calculate the [expectation value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case).